# In python, apply path (URL) of unknown length to a JSON object

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion

Given paths (*foos*) of unknown length, and associated values (*bars*):

```
foo1 = '/path/key1'
foo2 = '/path/node1/key2'
bar1 = 'value1'
bar2 = 'value2'
```

How can I recursively map these to a json structure, for example using python's json module?  The above would become:

```
{ 'path':
  { 'key1': 'value1',
    'node1': { 'key2': 'value2' }
  }
}
```

The aforementioned json module supports:

```
json_data['path']['key1'] = bar1
json_data['path']['node1']['key2'] = bar2
```

But I don't know the depth of each path provided...?!

Comment: this seems like a school assignment. can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: Seems like it, but I think that's just the way I've presented the problem, I've removed pretty much all context.  The reality is I couldn't see any question on SO that covers this challenge, so figured it would be worthwhile adding.

Comment: All you've got to do is use recursion/implement a custom class

Comment: @muddyfish how would you recursively represent the list of "directories" when constructing the assignment statement?

Comment: Look at the str.split method

Comment: I think I'm not explaining the challenge well enough.  Getting the paths in a list isn't a problem, but what isn't so simple is recursively generating the assignment statement, ie. json_data[item1][item2] - I should have mentioned that I don't want to use `exec`!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a recursive dictionary, you can use this helper class

```
class RecursiveDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, attr):
        db = RecursiveDict()
        super(RecursiveDict, self).__setitem__(attr, db)
        return db

    def __setitem__(self, attr, value):
        if isinstance(attr, (tuple,list)):
            cur = self[attr[0]]
            for i in attr[1:-1]:
                cur = cur[i]
            cur[attr[-1]] = value
        else:
            super(RecursiveDict, self).__setitem__(attr, value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, (tuple, list)):
            cur = self[item[0]]
            for i in item[1:]:
                cur = cur[i]
            return cur
        else:
            return super(RecursiveDict, self).__getitem__(item)

    def __delitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, (tuple, list)):
            cur = self[item[0]]
            for i in item[1:-1]:
                cur = cur[i]
            del cur[item[-1]]
        else:
            return super(RecursiveDict, self).__delitem__(item)
```

Use like:

```
a=RecursiveDict()

path="/a/a/a"
path = path.strip("/").split("/")

a[path]="value"
a["a","b","c"]=1
a["b"]=2
print a
```

--> `{'a': {'a': {'a': 'value'}, 'b': {'c': 1}}, 'b': 2}`

Comment: Can you see my latest comment?  It's the last line in your "use" that is the challenge.... how to do that when you don't know if the paths are a-c or a-z ??

Comment: @GMeister that better?

Comment: Let me try that out :)

Comment: The key that I was looking for is demonstrated in `a["a","b","c"]=1` which allows me to recursively generate a tuple to be applied to the RecursiveDict.  Thanks!

Comment: My last comment is valid, but I just realised your first usecase is exactly what I want, without the recursive tuple generation.  Simplicity!

Comment: You could add these: def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, (tuple, list)):
            cur = self[item[0]]
            for i in item[1:]:
                cur = cur[i]
            return cur
        else:
            return super(RecursiveDict, self).__getitem__(item)

    def __delitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, (tuple, list)):
            cur = self[item[0]]
            for i in item[1:-1]:
                cur = cur[i]
            del cur[item[-1]]
        else:
            return super(RecursiveDict, self).__delitem__(item)

Comment: Bonus gold star for someone who can prevent a['nonexistant_key'] from creating an empty dict due to the \_\_missing__ override